# On which dataset evaluate an object detection model ? Similar or real life data?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, object-detection

I'm training an object detection model (SSD300) to detect and classify body poses in thermal images.

Even I have more than 2k different poses, but **the background does not change much** (I have only 5 different points of view).

I trained my model on these images (70% for the training and 30% for validation).

**Now, I want to evaluate** the model on an unbiased dataset.

**Should I keep images of my dataset for this purpose or should I use a real life dataset ?**

(A good solution would be to have a real life training set, but I don't have)

I tried both, but as expected, I have an mAP=0.9 when evaluated on similar pictures and mAP=0.5 when evaluated on completely different images.

**Bonus question**: is mAP a relevant metric when I want to show result to a client ? (e.g a client doesn't understand if I tell him "my model has a mAP=0.7")

Precision-Recall ? (but I have to choose a pose classification threshold...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I keep images of my dataset for this purpose or should I use a
>   real life dataset ?

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you ultimately care about the performance on your dataset (perhaps you wish to compare with other models also benchmarked on this dataset), then you should evaluate on it. If you ultimately want to deploy the model on real life images, then you should evaluate on real life data.

> unbiased dataset

I don't think that a dataset can be biased or unbiased. Evaluating on an dataset drawn from distribution $P$ will result in an unbiased estimate of the performance of your model on distribution $P$ (but not necessarily any other distribution).

Comment: Maybe I missused the word "unbiased". I just wanted to say : on images that have not be seen by the model (during training or validation)